# Help me get started

Tags: safety

I have never done woodworking, but it seems cool and I would love to become good at it, where should I start? where did you start?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Tina, welcome to StackExchange. This type of query is not a good fit for SE I'm afraid as it's a strict Q&A venue. You'll get much better input on an open-ended query like this on a conventional woodworking forum. Since you'll be asked to provide this kind of info anyway, provide as much detail as you can, e.g. what are you hoping to do *now*? Hand or power tools or both? Initial budget? Be realistic about budget, while woodworking can be done relatively inexpensively (mainly by concentrating on hand tools) setting yourself up initially is hard to do on the cheap if buying everything new.

Comment: Pick an initial project, and start researching ways to build it. There are always several ways to do any given operation in woodworking, so don't take the first explanation you come across as the gospel truth. This will start to give you an idea of what kinds of tools you'll be interested in having, what kind of budget you'll need, etc.

Comment: Charlie Kilian and Graphus, thank you sooo much for your suggestions! I will make sure to ask better questions in the future, so that my posts are in line with this community's standards! Meanwhile I think I have a first project, I will try to make a chair as a gift for my friend's housewarming. Still not sure on the budget part, but will do my best to figure it out in the upcoming days.

Comment: You should check your local community college to see if they offer beginner woodworking courses. For just a little cash you can get access to a shop and expert advice, and more importantly, connections to the local amateur woodworking scene. You may also be lucky enough to live in a town with a shared woodworking/maker club you can join. Again, cheap access to a shop.

Comment: Steve Ramsey at Woodworking for Mere Mortals put together a list of tools to set up your shop for $1000, and includes pretty much everything you'd need to take on a bunch of projects. You can sign up to get the list on his [website](https://woodworkingformeremortals.com/). This would be a good starting point, and you can tailor it as needed for your chair project

Comment: Ana White makes a very accessible site. She has a whole section dedicated to getting started: http://www.ana-white.com/2012/12/get-started (Of course, this is like the 3rd time this link has moved, so expect it to be dead in an internet moment.)

Comment: Be careful with Ana White. She has a tendency to ignore wood movements in her designs, which will almost certainly lead to problems down the road. At most, I'd use her as inspiration. Run your intended design by someone knowledgeable before you build something from that site.

Comment: @mmathis, $1,000 is a massive starting budget by the standards of this side of the pond. Not only that it far exceeds the *necessary* spend for a lot of people who will only ever be doing smaller projects, esp. if they're comfortable using hand tools for many/most of the tasks needless to say. By concentrating on hand tools and limiting purchases to must-haves, and particularly with some careful buying of vintage stuff, you can build up a fully operational workshop for about half that. As an example Record QR vices are commonly available for under £40, and they're far better than any new vice.

Comment: @Graphus for sure, $1000 is a lot for a beginner to spend. My point was to use that as a guide with the specific project in mind, and get only what is needed. A lot of people are a bit overwhelmed on what to get, especially when watching professional woodworkers on youtube and think you need to spend hundreds or thousands on each tool - and that's just not true.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Buy a circular saw and a drill. Best tools you could own. You could build lots of things with those 2 simple tools.

Comment: Thank you @Nate for your answer! Do you have any specific brand in mind for either?

Comment: I would recommend Dewalt or Bosch. Makita makes excellent tools but they are very expensive. It's up to you. Thanks, Nate.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto the above I have seen impressive things made from pallets and bits of other materials. The tools in my shop range from the very best to bargain basement, many of my tools were used. simple and impressive are turnings pens,bottle stoppers, ... a small lathe can be had fairly cheaply around $200 new, I have turned 200+ pens on one. You will also need turning tools and a drill press that would put you at around $400 not so cheap.